# How to assign shortcuts to git svn in intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-svn, git-branch

Anyone know a way to assign a shortcut to git svn dcommit in intellij ? Even better to be able to combine it with the commit altogether.

Actually come to think of it perhaps a branch specific commit hook is the way to go, not sure how to do that either though

Comment: You have the problem that `git svn dcommit` rewrites history, not sure how IDEA handles that

Comment: It seems to manage ok when I do this externally, just resyncs everything with the filesystem when necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that git svn is [not supported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5677) in IntelliJ IDEA. A workaround may be to set up External Tools to run the required commands and then assign keyboard shortcuts to these tools.

Answer (score 0):

[SubGit](http://subgit.com/) provides a great opportunity to use IntelliJ built-in git support with existing Subversion repository.

SubGit works on the server side: once you install it into your Subversion repository, it enables Git access to this repository.

For more details refer to [SubGit documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation/) and [git-svn comparison](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html).